# How do I add project-specific information to the Git commit comment?

Tags: git, version-control

With Git, if you are committing, it includes a section under the commit message that is commented out. This contains instructions on writing a commit message as well as a list of files that are changing. Like this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:  important-file.txt 
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   some-other-thing.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       untracked.txt
```

Is it possible to add further material to this file? One clear use case is for those using issue tracking software like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and the like is specifying extra syntactical elements. Redmine users, for instance, can include the issue number and some special keywords to mark issues as resolved: the keywords are "refs" (and "references") and "fixes" (or "closes") - but I often find it difficult to remember the keywords.

It would be handy, then, if one could append some project-specific text at the bottom of the commit instructions.

Is there any existing way of doing this or do I need to hack one in? As a side issue, do any other VCSes (like Mercurial) have similar behaviour?

Comment: Note that even if you do this, not all users will see it. For example, I often commit from SourceTree, which doesn’t open an editor and so never shows the commit message template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used a commit.template (as described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/ch8-1.html#committemplate-7kT8HRswI4)). I could have used a prepare-commit-msg hook, but a commit template does the job slightly easier, plus I can keep the commit template in the version control for the project.

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1:

As others have mentioned, the direct way to do this with Git is the [prepare-commit-message](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) hook.

However, there are issues with that strategy that must be considered.  From Chapter 7.4 of Pro Git:

> [Client-side hook scripts] aren’t
>   transferred with a clone of a
>   project, you must distribute these
>   scripts some other way and then have
>   your users copy them to their
>   .git/hooks directory and make them
>   executable. You can distribute these
>   hooks within the project or in a
>   separate project, but there is no way
>   to set them up automatically.

### Option 2:

As mentioned by [Tom Morris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195303/how-do-i-add-project-specific-information-to-the-git-commit-comment/3195612#3195612), use a [commit template](https://git-scm.com/book/ch8-1.html#committemplate-7kT8HRswI4).

### Option 3:

You could do a custom build of Git which includes your additional instructions.  The instructions included in the current commit message are hard-coded in the Git source code.  See `$GIT_SRC/builtin/commit.c` starting at [line 655](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/commit.c).

This method is probably not preferred since you would have to apply the patch every time a new version of Git is released.

### Option 4:

Create a patch for Git which adds this feature and submit it to the mailing list.  If you (or others) decide to try this, I would first ask for advice from the list on how to proceed.

---

### Mercurial:

Hook scripts in Mercurial behave in a similar manner.  From [Chapter 10](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) of Mercurial: The Definitive Guide:

> In Mercurial, hooks are not revision
>   controlled, and do not propagate when
>   you clone, or pull from, a repository.
>   The reason for this is simple: a hook
>   is a completely arbitrary piece of
>   executable code. It runs under your
>   user identity, with your privilege
>   level, on your machine.
>
> It would be extremely reckless for any
>   distributed revision control system to
>   implement revision-controlled hooks,
>   as this would offer an easily
>   exploitable way to subvert the
>   accounts of users of the revision
>   control system.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak the commit message via the `prepare-commit-message` [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could use a prepare-commit-msg hook for this. Take a look at [githooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) for more information.